# Matlab finding prime numbers in a number

Tags: matlab

```
a=input('Number:');   
check=0;   
sum=0;   
counter=0;   
result=0;   
while a >=0  
    b=mod(a,10);  
    for i=2:b-1
        if mod(b,i)==0
            check=check+1;
        end
    end
    if check==0
        sum=sum+b;
        counter=counter+1;
    end
    a=a/10;
    check=0;
end
result=sum/counter;
disp(result);
```

Hi everyone i want to find prime numbers in a given number and calculate their average but i dont know why program stucks in a loop when i enter a number.Can anyone help me with my issue

Comment: What do you mean with "prime numbers in a number"? Can you phrase that mathematically exact, or at least give an example?

Comment: sorry my english is not good i mean the given number is 12345 for example.and i want to take 2 3 5 and calculate their average @MarcusMüller

Comment: so, you're only after the four single digit prime numbers "2 3 5 7"?

Comment: yes but i dont want to check  them if they are 2 3 5 7 i want to check with my algorithm is it wrong?

Comment: I don't understand, you want to check for them, but you don't want to check for them?

Comment: i want to check for them.but i dont want to use `if b== 2 || 3 || 5 || 7` i want to  use a loop like i wrote

Comment: hm, ok (aside from `if b==2||3||5||7` not being matlab syntactically what you think they are), but that's a really bad approach.

Comment: i know its bad i can write the code in c++ and it works well but when it comes to matlab i cant even do this cant see the problem syntaxes are correct  but i cant just cant pls help

Comment: workspace says b= 1.00000e-323 when i write 1 for a how is this even possible

Comment: no, your syntax is **not** correct, and I swear, in C++, `b==2||3||5||7` doesn't even remotely work that way. So, you need to learn matlab syntax. don't do that by writing code that is *logically* bad.

Comment: i didnt say it was correct syntax i just said that to show what i dont want to use.my english skill is not great as i said.thats why we cant communicate properly :(

Answer (score 0):

It's because of `a >= 0`. I think you rather want `a > 0`

Comment: Yeah stucking in the loop is gone but the values of variables is way too wrong this time

Comment: you should reset `check` to 0. And `sum` and `counter`, too

Comment: but if  i reset `sum` and `counter` to 0 i cant find the average also i reset `check` to 0 but values are still random

Comment: right, `sum` and `counter` should not be reset, but `check` at the end of the while loop

Comment: yes check = 0 at the end of while loop but result is still wrong